# Cannot Access Play! Internal Actor System

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, playframework-2.0

I'm following the documentation [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaAkka) as I would like to add [Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html) to the application-provided actor system. I try to import the application actor system with:

```
import play.libs.concurrent.Akka
```

I'm using `sbt compile` to invoke my compilation and receive the following error

```
[error] app/controllers/Application.scala:9: object concurrent is not a member of package play.libs
[error] import play.libs.concurrent.Akka
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
```

#### conf/pplication.conf

```
#Disable DBPlugin
dbplugin=disabled

#Disable DB evolutions
evolutionplugin=disabled

#Disable Eh Cache
ehcacheplugin=disabled


# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG

akka.default-dispatcher.core-pool-size-max = 64
akka.debug.receive = on
```

#### project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "SomeCoolApp"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
      "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % "2.+"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
    )

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the Play! 2.0 internal actor system, use

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system
```

Refer to the [API doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$) for the correct implementation.

Comment: The link should be:  `...#play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$` but Markdown changes it to `...#...Akka%24` which results in a broken link.

Comment: I tried fixing it but no luck, if you have an idea please go ahead and edit the link.

Comment: This is deprecated since play 2.5.0
You should inject ActorSystem instead